# I cannot remember my password to the wireless router i am connected to

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, wireless-router, password-recovery

I am currently using a Dell laptop using windows XP and I am connected to a wireless router. I wish to find out the password to the router to connect a desktop without resetting the router as that would agitate the people also using this router. The problem is that the password is managed using the Dell Wireless WLAN Card Utility and I cannot find any program that can interact with it. Are there any tips and tricks to finding this password myself, or any programs I may have missed?

Comment: the password to connect to the access point or the configration page, either way, brute force is your only alternative depending on the length of the password could take forever

Comment: It would be eaier just to reset the router or ask somebody for the password

Comment: Can you clarify which password?  I suspect from your post you meen the passphrase for WIFI, but this is different to the router password.  You can bypass the need for a passphrase by plugging your desktop in with an ethernet cable until such time as you can rest the AP settings on the router.    There are a number of ways you can hack the AP credentials, but thats probably a step to far for SU, and it would be easier to reset the AP anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of five things to look for:-

1. Routers are usually delivered with default administrator and wireless passwords, printed either on the router or in the supplied documentation.
2. If you made changes, and can log into the router's web interface, you may find the password displayed in the wireless LAN set-up, depending on the router type.
3. Check other machines on the wireless network: they may be able to display the password in their wireless settings.
4. If you know which machine was used to set up the router, you may find that the passwords were saved in its browser.
5. Finally, you can look for likely places in your file system or registry to see where the Dell utility saved its data.

Browsing the router settings should not interrupt the router, provided you do not change anything which requires a reboot.